# Code works on JS fiddle but not on my website

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, jsfiddle

I am trying to make a search history log using Local Storage in HTML and I am currently trying to understand how to use the local storage function. Now I have run into an odd problem.

This example works great: http://jsfiddle.net/hr3xQ/17/

But when I try to put it together on my server nothing happens when I try to run the code

```
    <!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
<script type='text/javascript'> 

$(function () {

    $("#submit").click(function () {
        var name = $("#name").val();
        localStorage.setItem('username',name);
        alert(localStorage.getItem('username'));

    });
});  

</script>

</head>
<body>

    name:
<input type="text" id="name">
<br/>
<br/>
<input type="button" id="submit" value="store in local">

</body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm not very used to web-programming.

Comment: You didn't include jQuery. It works in your fiddle because jQuery is already included there.

Comment: One of the most common mistakes... include jquery then you can use jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to [include jQuery](http://jquery.com/download/) if you want to use jQuery.

In JSFiddle, you get a nice little toggle that allows you to select the frameworks/libraries you'd like to include.

However, when you move your code, the jQuery inclusion doesn't come along with you. You need to either download it or include it via a `script` tag in the `head` (do it above your other `script` so that jQuery loads before you try to use it:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
```

This is a very common problem: whenever `nothing happens`, it's a good idea to check your browser's console. For not including jQuery, you'll often get something like this:

```
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

Comment: Great answer thank you. I solved it already with Kith's answer but yours was a but more detailed so I'll choose yours as the answer. Sorry @Kith

Answer (score 3):

You need to include jQuery in your HTML

http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/

EDIT: Changed reference link to avoid getting lynched

Comment: Where'd everyone get those nice pitchforks and torches?

Comment: @Huangism there's nothing wrong with the w3 link in this case and even though it's not an officially recognized resource, in 90% of the cases it presents correct information.

Comment: w3 has helped me plenty during my career. It may not always be correct, but I'm not sure why there's so much animosity towards it.

Comment: @Tyblitz I am 100% sure that my comment did not say there is anything wrong with anything

Comment: @Kith I think the animosity comes from the fact that it is not correct 100% of the time and it is not actually related to W3C. It's none of my business if anyone wants to use. I think people don't like it because it is very possible that a beginner will use this link for other issues where it can have misleading info when someone links it here. So while it is fine for this but it might lead to future issues for the OP

Comment: @Huangism fair enough. I'll provide a disclaimer next time I link them lol